# php update multiple raw

Tags: php, html, sql

I have made this:

```
<?php
$query1=mysql_query("select * from addd");
?>

<form method="post" action="bulkreload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<?php
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
?>

ID: <input type="text" cols="50" name="id<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>"/>
Email: <input type="text" cols="50" name="email<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $query2['email']; ?>"/>
Age:<input type="text" name="age<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $query2['age']; ?>" />

<?php
}
?>

<input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit">

</form>
```

With this code i take all data from `addd`.
My object is: Update all data with a single submit button.

I think  i need to use a php cycle for update every data but I have no idea how to create it.

Inside bulkreload.php i have this:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];

$email=$_POST['email'];

$age=$_POST['age'];

$query3=mysql_query("update addd set email='$email', age='$age' where id='$id'");


if ($query3) {
echo "News Updated";
}
```

Don't work because is build for take data on sigle article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST keys now contain both the key AND the id.

Try this for your form:

```
ID: <input type="text" cols="50" name="row[<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>"/>

Email: <input type="text" cols="50" name="row[<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>][email]; ?>" value="<?php echo $query2['email']; ?>"/>

Age:<input type="text" name="row[<?php echo $query2['id']; ?>][age]" value="<?php echo $query2['age']; ?>" />
```

This will produce a POST array similar to:

```
$_POST['row'] = array(
    1 => array(
         'id'= > 1,
         'email' => 'your_1_email',
         'age' => 'your_1_age'
    ),
    // more lines here
    N => array(
         'id'= > N,
         'email' => 'your_N_email',
         'age' => 'your_N_age'
    )
);
```

it will contain N arrays and your `insert` will become:

```
$post = $_POST['row'];
foreach($post as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $age = $row['age'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $query = mysql_query(
        "update addd set email='$email', age='$age'  where id='$id'"
    );
    if ($query) {
        echo "News Updated";
    }
}
```

Note, yes, you *can* nest the `POST` array ;)